# When I ran an update (apt update) it gave me a problem

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

When I ran an update (apt update) it gave me a

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi

E: Sub-process returned an error code` error.
```

Also it complained about some python apt_pkg libraries.

I have 3rd side grapejuice repository included to apt config file." What should I do to use apt update?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: 20.04.4 LTS Ubuntu Linux

Comment: I had some apt problems a few times n Kubuntu  that were solved by using the system software manager instead (Discover)

Comment: Have you made changes to python3?  What version are you getting by default, ie. `python3 --version; python --version` as Ubuntu has many tools that will no longer function correctly if default python3 is changed.

Comment: my python version is 3.10.5 , 
but about changes idk im update python version with metod like that :|||

python -v |||
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
|||
 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.10 2
|||
 sudo update-alternatives --config python3
|||

 python -v

Comment: Yeap, you broke your system. Reinstallation is in order.

Comment: okeeeeyyyyyyy:<